# Scroll to clicked/open div and offset by previously opened div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The issue I have here is how to scroll to the top of a div that is clicked on when the other one closes.  I can make it work if no divs are open, but if one is it fails to scroll to the top of the newly opened div.  I am assuming I need to offset by the old open div.  Not sure how to go about it though.  Here is the fiddle for easy reference - http://jsfiddle.net/dnym5p1s/3/

Shortened code:
HTML:

```
<div class="option-heading">
 <h1>Year1 <span class="arrow-up">&#9650;</span><span class="arrow-down">&#9660;</span></h1>
</div>
<div class="option-content">ContentContentContent <br />Content <br />Content <br />Content <br />Content <br />Content <br />Content <br />Content <br />Content <br />Content <br />Content <br />Content <br />Content <br />Content <br />Content <br />Content <br />Content <br />Content <br />Content <br />Content</div>

<div class="option-heading">
     <h1>Year2 <span class="arrow-up">&#9650;</span><span class="arrow-down">&#9660;</span></h1>
</div>
<div class="option-content">Content <br />Content <br />Content <br />Content <br />Content <br />Content <br />Content <br />Content <br />Content <br />Content <br />Content <br />Content <br />Content <br />Content <br />Content <br />Content <br />Content <br />Content <br />Content <br />Content <br />Content <br />Content <br />Content <br />Content <br />Content <br />Content <br />Content <br />vContent <br />Content <br />Content <br />Content <br />Content <br />Content <br />Content <br />Content <br />Content <br />Content <br />Content <br />Content <br />Content <br /></div>
```

CSS:

```
.option-heading h1 {
    margin:0;
    padding:8px 5px;
    font-size:19px
}
.option-content h4 {
    color: #900027;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin:25px 0 0
}
.option-content p {
    margin-top:0
}
.option-content {
    border-bottom: 10px solid #800202;
    border-top: 10px solid #800202;
}
.arrow-up,.arrow-down{color:#647f8a;cursor:pointer;width:20px; font-size:10px; padding:0 0 0 10px;vertical-align:middle}
```

jQuery:

```
$('.option-content,.arrow-up, .arrow-down:first').hide();
$('.option-content:first,.arrow-up:first').show();
$('.option-heading').click(function () {
    $('.option-content').not($(this).next()).slideUp(250);
    $('.option-heading').not(this).find('span.arrow-up').hide();
    $('.option-heading').not(this).find('span.arrow-down').show();
    $(this).next('.option-content').slideToggle(250);
    $(this).find('.arrow-up, .arrow-down').toggle();
//Jump to Open Div
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $(this).offset().top - 10}, 'fast');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hiding the content, store the top offset of each `option-heading`:

```
$('.option-content,.arrow-up, .arrow-down:first').hide();

$('.option-heading').each(function() {
  $(this).data('top', $(this).offset().top - 10);
});
```

You can then animate the `scrollTop` to that position:

```
$('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $(this).data('top')}, 'fast');
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/5ydkjaw8/)

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking to do.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not that you have to offset by the old open div: it's only a problem if the old open div is above the new one, which means that it's an issue of the relative location of the new div changing during the animation. (If the old div is below the new one, the location of the new div does not change during animation.)

To remedy this, you need to [queue](http://api.jquery.com/queue/) the animations, so that the scroll occurs *after* the old div closes.

Comment: I'll take a look into queue as it seems to be the solution - to do the scroll after the close.  Out of curiosity though, is there no way to house the height of the old div and offset the scrollto dynamically with that value only if the div is above?  Not that this is good practice, but I would like to see how someone would go about it.

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be to give the headings a id

```
<h1 id="4">Year4 ....
```

and to navigate with the loaction attribute to

```
yoururl.com/index.html#4
```

works like a charm.. maybe not in jsfiddle tough

Comment: Note that your ID can start with a non-alphabetical character in HTM5 only, not in previous versions of HTML.